# File reading and RE parsing

Tags: python, regex, file

I've a strange behaviour that I don't understand :

If I open my file , I find my bytes , but only once at a time :

```
f = open('d:\BB.ki', "rb")
f10 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x10''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', f.read() )
print f10
['1BBBAAAABBBBAAAABBBBAAAABBBBAAAA\x00']

f = open('d:\BB.ki', "rb")
f11 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x11''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', f.read() )
print f11
['2AAABBBBAAAABBBBAAAA\x00']
```

If I try to opening the file and getting severall bytes , I only get the 1st one (f11 is empty )

```
f = open('d:\BB.ki', "rb")
f10 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x10''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', f.read() )
f11 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x11''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', f.read() )
print f10,f11
['1BBBAAAABBBBAAAABBBBAAAABBBBAAAA\x00'] **[]**
```

May I use a loop , or something similar ?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you can always do `f.seek(0)` to reset the file stream pointer to the beginning of the file, and then the second `read()` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

After you call `f.read()` there are no more bytes available to be read so a second call to `f.read()` will return an empty string. Store the result of f.read() instead of reading twice:

```
s = f.read()
f10 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x10''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
f11 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x11''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

You may also want to scan the data just a single time, finding both expressions:

```
matches = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00[\x10\x11]''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

If your file contains the bytes `'\x03\x00\x00\x10\x03\x00\x00\x11_\xF7\x00\xF0'` the method you proposed will find two overlapping matches (`\x03\x00\x00\x11_` and `_`), whereas the single scan approach finds only a single match.

Comment: Great ! the 1st solution is what I needed , THX :)

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` consumes the entire file. only f10 will seen.

try this maybe.

```
 for line in open('d:\BB.ki', "rb").readlines():
    f10 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x10''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', line )
    f11 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x11''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', line )
```